# Link TransactionScope TransactionInformation Transaction Identifier with sql server transaction ids

Tags: c#, sql-server, transactions, transactionscope, cdc

I am using the TransactionScope class in my wcf services to group any database operations in my wcf services into one transaction.  I am alos using sql server change data capture to capture all changes on tables in question.

I would like to be able to report all database cdc change back to the original service operation where my transaction scope is created.

So say i have  service operation called SavePolicy which actually does 3 db updates in one transaction scope.  In that scope I can get a transaction Id using code like:

```
TransactionInformation info = Transaction.Current.TransactionInformation;                
transactionId = Guid.Empty == info.DistributedIdentifier ? info.LocalIdentifier : info.DistributedIdentifier.ToString();
```

Is this id stored anywhere in sql server?  I am using entity framework and stored procedures to do regular crud operations.

I can get all the change data using cdc functions like fn_cdc_get_all_changes_ and there is a transaction id in the cdc.lsn_time_mapping table but it doesn't look like this is the same thing.

I was hoping that I could store the c# transaction scope along with a database transaction id or log sequence number and the service method name so I could report cdc changes by service operation name.

Any help or thoughts would be great!
Ryan

Answer (score 0):

Transaction id's are not stored in sql server when the transaction is committed. It sounds more like the application wants some additional tracking and the data model does not have that information.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to create that information. In fact we are already manually storing transaction history in our own table as well as in cdc. CDC was addeded after the fact for our DataWareHouse consumption. I was hoping that at the time of an update the app could store a transaction and operation name linking it to the CDC data instead of adding another history record.  To report we would later look up the transaction number and join it to the cdc.